# URL Encoded Parameter Unit Test

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, json

I'm trying to extract encoded URL params from a visual force page but I seem to be getting a JSON exception when I do so.

```
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('m', EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSON.serialize(outgoingMessage), 'UTF-8')); 
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('ah', EncodingUtil.urlEncode(expectedMac, 'UTF-8'));
```

In this example, the **outgoingMessage** is of type MyObject (custom object defined as an inner class) to store user data and expectedMac is a string. I'm injecting these params in a test class to mirror the behavior of a request to a visual force page. Once the params are injected, I want to grab them within a controller.

```
    message            = String.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('m'));
    senderMacString    = String.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ah')); 

    try{
        incomingMsg  = (MyObject)JSON.deserialize(message, MyObject.class);
    }
    catch(JSONException j){
        System.debug(j.getMessage());
        NotAuthorizedPage();
    }
```

To my knowledge, getParameters() will decode the url in utf-8 by default, so I don't need to call use the EncodingUtil.decode method. However, I seem to be getting an error when I try to deserialize that message:

```
Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *non-test* you are correct that the pageReference is decoded.

However in a test method you need to decode it within the test.

I will work up a POC in a few minutes:

Here is a test VF Page to show it works without decoding in NON-test Context

**Page**

```
<apex:page id="examplePR" controller="examplePR">
    {!result}
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class examplePR {
    public string result {
        get{
            System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('example'));
            return ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('example');
        }
    }

}
```

Hit with the following URL:

> https://[instanceURL]/apex/examplePR?example=12%21%40%2634%3F%3D

Results

[image]

> 09:43:09.0 (112324756)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|12!@&34?=

Now here are the test method examples

```
@IsTest
private class examplePRTest {
    static testMethod void testBehavior() {
        String toEncode = '12!@&34?=';

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('example',EncodingUtil.urlEncode(toEncode,'UTF-8'));
        System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('example'));

        System.assertEquals(
                toEncode,
                EncodingUtil.urlDecode(
                        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('example')
                        ,'UTF-8'
                )
        );

        System.debug(
                EncodingUtil.urlDecode(
                        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('example')
                        ,'UTF-8'
                )
        );

    }
}
```

> 09:34:05.1 (2081135)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|12%21%40%2634%3F%3D
>
> 09:34:05.1 (2117304)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|12!@&34?=

One of the quirks of testing is that you will need to decode any URL parameters that you get during the test method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. For my implementation, I added isTest system method to my controller to properly decode the URL params based on the current context.